# pymongo find_one retruning None when used in discord.py command but working fine in terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, discord.py, pymongo

This is the document I'm searching for in my collection.

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5fef0220e37ad50a37582bc1'), 'nationid': 176311, 'nation': 'Markovia', 'leader': 'Sam Cooper', 'continent': 'Africa', 'war_policy': 'Pirate', 'color': 'beige', 'alliance': 'Arrgh', 'allianceid': 913, 'allianceposition': 3, 'cities': 19, 'infrastructure': 11400, 'offensivewars': 0, 'defensivewars': 
0, 'score': 2283.09, 'rank': 10, 'vacmode': 0, 'minutessinceactive': 50, 'query_nation': 'markovia', 'query_leader': 'sam cooper'}
```

I have this function that is supposed to enable to me search with a `"nationid"`, `"query_nation"` or `"query_leader"`:

```
def find_nation(nation):
    if nation.isnumeric():
        nation = int(nation)
        return db.nations.find_one({"nationid":nation})
    else:
        result = db.nations.find_one({"query_nation":nation.lower()})
        if result:
            return result
        else:
            return db.nations.find_one({"query_leader":nation.lower()})
```

This command works fine when I search for `176311` and `markovia` but returns None for `sam cooper`

```
@client.command()
async def nation(ctx, nation):
    nation_dict_1 = find_nation(nation)
    if nation_dict_1:
        await ctx.send(f'{nation_dict_1["leader"]} of {nation_dict_1["nation"]}')
    else:
        await ctx.send('Could not find an exact match.')
```

However when I use this in terminal, it works fine with all 3 and prints the document every time. (with `sam cooper` too)

```
nation_dict_1 = find_nation(nation)
if nation_dict_1:
    print(nation_dict_1)
else:
    print('Could not find an exact match.')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with how your arguments are being passed into the command. `sam cooper` won't work due to the space in the middle. To fix this, you can use the "consume rest" functionality of the asterisk.

Try this, your rewritten command:

```
@client.command()
async def nation(ctx, *, nation):
    nation_dict_1 = find_nation(nation)
    if nation_dict_1:
        await ctx.send(f'{nation_dict_1["leader"]} of {nation_dict_1["nation"]}')
    else:
        await ctx.send('Could not find an exact match.')
```

Your current command would work if you did:
`!nation "sam cooper"`
But using the asterisk will allow you to enter arguments without the quotations.

---

### References:

- [FAQ - Why do my args require quotes](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?#why-do-my-arguments-require-quotes)

Comment: ah damn, I'd totally forgotten about this, thank you!